# "SSIS" using up lots of system performance and burning through my battery. How to fix this?

Tags: 20.04, mssql

I had my system updated yesterday and I can remember that "SSIS for Linux" (SQL Server Integration Services ) had a huge 200MB update in this.

Today I was working on my notebook (Thinkpad T14) and I noticed, that the coolers are running pretty much all the time. I also noticed that my battery gets drained much faster than before.

I had a look at HTOP and found that user "ssis" had a lot of tasks running, about 5 of them using up 5 of my 12 cpu threats for about 90 to 100% each.

I had installed ssis about a month ago because I tried to get into some Business Develoment Topics on mssql-server 2016. So far I had no issues with it. It seems like the update yesterday broke something or maybe its bugged?

I already disabled mssql-server on my notebook using systemctrl. Surprisingly all the ssis tasks are still running and using most of my notebooks resources.

I removed ssis for now from my system and cooling/power usage are back to normal. However, I would like to continue to use this in the future.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: If you’re somewhat familiar with Docker or virtual machines, it might make sense to run SSIS (or even SQL Server) in an isolated, on-demand manner. Unless SSIS is being used extensively all day every day, there’s no need to let occasional-use software to run continuously in the background 

Comment: This is definitely an option for my development environment, however I will have to move the solution to my server at some point and I am afraid, that this issue will show up there as well and SSIS / SQL-Server will run 24/7.